# Did Khadija RA continue to do business after her marriage with prophet SAW?

Tags: history, business, seerah, wives-of-the-prophet

if she did continue business after her marriage, can you also please add the answer to-- approximately after how many years of marriage did she retire from her business?

Please specify whether the source of answer is sunni or shia

Comment: Oh yes she invested in Allah Islam and Muhammad. Best Tijara ever.

Comment: Well one could say that as there was no clear mentioning that she stopped her business, that it went along, the prophet () himself never stopped doing business even if he was not known to do it on regular basis.

Comment: @LostInSpace i am aware that she spent on the prophet but it doesn't say if she invested from "her savings" or "from her income of the ongoing business", so that's the ambiguity I wanted to clear up

Comment: You're right. Islam has never forbidden women to do business so I see no reason why she would have stopped doing business.

Answer (score 1):

This video might answer your question https://youtu.be/ceqol1opGT8?t=128. I've copied the link at that specific time, but do listen from the start, for proper context.

**Note:** Video is in urdu. Just a portion of it is summarized below

It says

Even after the marriage Muhammad S.A.W.W continued doing the same business with Khadijah R.A i.e. taking her goods and selling it in another place; and Khadijah R.A was the owner then. But when Muhammad S.A.W.W became a Prophet, then considering the responsibilities of a prophet; Khadijah R.A handed over all her goods/business to Prophet Muhammad S.A.W.W and made him the owner …

Comment: Would it be possible [edit] to include a summary of the conclusions from the YouTube video please?

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks for the information Zain.